# How to construct a GET parameter in router On zend

Tags: zend-framework, url

I'm new to Zend Frame work, can any one help to constract below in router,

http://hostname/recruiter/index/login?height=360&width=800&random=1334642212073

as
http://hostname/login

and other values has to be pass through router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your Bootstrap.php should look like:

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    /**
     * Define the URL routes here
     */
    public function _initRoutes()
    {
        // Get the router object
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();


        $routeLogin = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                        'login',
                        array(
                            'controller' => 'index',
                            'action' => 'login',
                        )
        );


        $router->addRoute('login', $routeLogin);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion,but i need to set height,width in router itself, it is possible.

Comment: do you want to redirect or set a default value?

Answer (score 0):

The code provided previously by maSnun is a great example to follow.

You can specify default parameters by adding them to the route definition.

```
        $routeLogin = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    'login',
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action' => 'login',
                        'height' => 360,
                        'width' => 800,
                    )
        );
```

You can then get height and width as usual with getParam().